# How to Sample from a DataFrame in Pandas to Match a Target Distribution with Specific Variables

Tags: python, pandas, filter, distribution, sampling

I'm working with a large DataFrame in Pandas, containing about 800,000 observations. I need to create a sample from this DataFrame that approximates a target distribution. The sample size should be around 10,000 observations.

There are five variables in my DataFrame that are of particular importance, and I want the sample distribution to closely match the target distribution for these variables. These variables, in order by priority, are:

borad_industry
ticket_size
years_in_business
business_type
employee_size_code
The challenge is to ensure that the sample distribution for these variables is as close as possible to the target distribution, with a tolerance of ±5%.

I'm looking for guidance or methods in Python, preferably using Pandas, that would allow me to achieve this. How can I sample from my DataFrame in a way that ensures the distribution of these five variables within the sample is within the specified tolerance of the target distribution?

Any suggestions or pointers towards relevant methods or libraries would be greatly appreciated

Here's what I've tried so far, but the distributions do not come very close to the targer:

```
# Helper function to sample according to target proportions, considering the minimum count and uniqueness
def sample_by_proportion_unique(df, column, proportions, min_count):
    # Get the unique identifiers to ensure we don't sample the same 'c_identity' more than once
    unique_ids = set(df['c_identity'])
    
    samples = []
    for value, proportion in proportions.items():
        # Calculate the required sample count for the category
        required_count = int(proportion * min_count)
        category_df = df[df[column] == value]
        
        # Sample without replacement
        sampled_ids = set(category_df['c_identity']).intersection(unique_ids)
        if len(sampled_ids) > required_count:
            sampled_ids = set(np.random.choice(list(sampled_ids), required_count, replace=False))
        
        # Update the unique ids to remove the ones we have already sampled
        unique_ids -= sampled_ids
        
        # Append the sampled data for this category
        samples.append(category_df[category_df['c_identity'].isin(sampled_ids)])
        
        # If we run out of unique identifiers, break early
        if len(unique_ids) == 0:
            break
    
    return pd.concat(samples)

# Sequentially adjust the sample according to the target distributions
min_observations = 10000
adjusted_sampled_df = sampled_df.copy()

for column in ['broad_industry', 'ticket_size', 'years_in_business']:
    adjusted_sampled_df = sample_by_proportion_unique(adjusted_sampled_df, column, target_distributions[column], min_observations)
    # Ensure we don't go below the minimum number of observations
    if len(adjusted_sampled_df) < min_observations:
        raise ValueError(f"Not enough unique observations to meet the minimum count for {column}")

# Check final sample size
final_sample_size = len(adjusted_sampled_df)
print(final_sample_size)  # This will print the size of the sampled dataframe
```

Comment: What do you mean by "target distribution"? Each variable likely has its own true distribution, but it is generally unknown. Your 800k observations are themselves just a sample. You can make hypotheses about what kind of underlying distribution these are drawn from. You may even test those against known distributions (and get a probabilistic answer). But trying to sub-sample, say, observations from a gaussian deviate to make them look uniform, while possible, would be lying to yourself. Please provide a simple example (e.g., small code generating data) along with the desired result.